# Is there a website showing membership stats for casting sites for actors?

Tags: casting

Is there a website or organisation which shows membership stats for online casting sites for actors? i.e. How many members does Actors Access/CCP/LA Casting etc have? I'm putting together a research paper and finding it hard to track this info down.

Comment: Have you tried contacting them directly? Sorry this is old but I just saw it... I've worked with both Casting Networks and Breakdown and, realistically, the numbers you get from an external source may not be very helpful, particularly if you're only interested in a specific region.